# Running java as a separate process in windows command line through uDeploy

Tags: java, command-line, udeploy

I have a UrbanCode Deploy process with a Command Line step that will run an executable jar `myjar.jar`

In Windows command line, to run as a separate process (so that the command line won't be blocked after I run the jar)

```
start java -jar myjar.jar
```

However if I run this command in a uDeploy step, the deploy process will just keep running (I assume it doesn't spawn a separate process).

How to achieve this via uDeploy? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Deamon option https://developer.ibm.com/urbancode/plugindoc/ibmucd/shell/1-2/steps/, this will run in the background and will not hold your current step for long